# Absolute div not taking 100% of the body

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to make my `absolute` red div take full body height. but the body seems to be a lot shorter than the height he was supposed to get because of `other` div.

HTML

```
<div class="abs"></div>
<div class="other">
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.abs
{
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
.other
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:solid black 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.toCenter
{
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
}
```

Comment: Increase the height and width of the .abs div to 1000%. Also why are you using a div to just get a background? Simply put the background on the body instead.

Comment: If you add `position:fixed` instead of `position: absolute;` the div will continue scrolling with the page. It might get you the result you're after.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova That's it you solve my problem than you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `position:fixed` instead of `position: absolute;` the div will continue scrolling with the page. It might get you the result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit your element in body with this `jQuery` code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
    $('your element').height(bodyHeight);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
  $('html,body').height(bodyHeight);
});
```

```css
html,body
{
  margin:0;
}
.abs
{
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.other
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:solid black 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.toCenter
{
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abs"></div>
<div class="other">
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
  <div class="toCenter"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

Dear If you want to set absolute position to div, then you have to set relative position to parent div, if there is no parents div then you can set relative position to body also.
because absolute position some time work depend on parent element position.

```
body{
  position : relative;
}
.abs
{
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` property can be replaced by the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` rules :

```
.ans {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

That should work, that's the method I always use in my codes. Please note that the div will no longer fill the parent but fill the entire page.